# Aggregate metric per date

Tags: looker-studio

I have a data source with data formatted like this:

| ID | Visits | Charges | Date | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 33 | 21 | 375 | 2022-01-29 | A |
| 34 | 4285 | 4400 | 2022-01-29 | B |
| 35 | 12 | 2165 | 2022-01-29 | C |
| 36 | 31 | 4285 | 2022-01-30 | A |
| 37 | 40 | 5881 | 2022-01-31 | A |
| 38 | 29 | 4715 | 2022-01-31 | B |
| 39 | 8 | 1390 | 2022-01-31 | C |

I want to get the aggregated visits of all locations per day, and from there getting the Max value of a day for the time period chosen by the user on a ScoreCard and a Table. At the moment when i choose the max value of the metric visits it only gives me the max value of column (4285), not for the aggregated data per day.

The value i am looking for, in the time period between 28-01 and 31-01 should be 4318 (the sum of all 3 locations  for the 29-01, which is the highest of the 3 days)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I may suggest is to use Pivot Table like this:

[image]

You choose Date as your row dimension. Then you choose Visits as metric (aggregation set as SUM).

Remember to sort this table by Visits in descending order. Your maximum value should be on top. If you want to see only this maximum value, you can change size of your pivot table to keep only first value visible.

This should work with additional controls too.